# .htaccess RewriteRule is not working

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule new/$ /search.php?category=1
RewriteRule new/\?(.+)$ /search.php?category=1&$1
```

I'm trying to do something like this, if the following address link is accessed,

```
http://onlineshop.com/new/
http://onlineshop.com/new/?price_max=30
```

then it will open this link,

```
http://onlineshop.com/new/search.php?category=1
http://onlineshop.com/new/search.php?category=1&price_max=30
```

Unfortunately it is not working this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RewriteRule` won't naturally catch query string parameters, you must use this kind of `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^new/$ /search.php?category=1&%1
```

Comment: A basic `RewriteRule` won't catch anything in the GET param, that's why your second rule doesn't work. My `RewriteCond` is here to put the query string in a variable (`%1`).

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply redirect from `/new` to `/search.php` **with QSA flag** and Apache will append the existing query string. Something like this will work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^new/?$ /search.php?category=1 [L,QSA,NC]
```